# Word Hunt: A Collection of Lessons, but a subset of a Course?

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, word-choice

I come from [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), a site about programming, and I feel my 
question is too broad for them, as it’s more about English, and less about
programming. This is more of a word-hunt than programming.

In short, I have a Database for a Web Application with different concepts 
within them, like *Users*, *Courses*, *Lessons*, etc. These concepts can
have any name, but because I’m picky, I like to use one-word names for my
concepts.

To explain how these concepts are related: I have *Lessons*, which are 
day-to-day exercises, like “Read this article”, or “Watch this video”.
They’re typically about learning a small subset of a broader subject, like
learning a Formula in a Math Class.

Then I have *Series*, which is the word in question that I would like to 
replace. Anyways, a *Series* is simply a collection of *Lessons*, to cover
a general subset of a broader subject. This would be like learning about
Quadratic Equations in Algebra. Each Formula is a *Lesson*, Quadratic
Equations is the *Series*, and Algebra is the *Course*.

As you might have guessed, the third concept involved is *Courses*. These 
are much broader subjects, which are broken down into *Series*, which are
then broken further down into *Lessons*.

The problem is: due to certain programming standards, Databases like to use 
words where a [Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_(database)) (or Concept) Name is the Plural Form of the
Concept, like *Courses*, and each entry in the Table can then be labelled
by its Singular Form, which would be *Course*, in this example. However,
once we start using words like *Series*, where its Singular and Plural
Forms are the same, distinguishing between the two can be troublesome.

Before you post ideas, there’s a few words that I’ve already rejected, 
because they weren’t quite what I was looking for:

- Group (I’m already using this for a Concept that depicts a Group of People)
- Collection (This is too vague. Something like *Series* has a unifying feel about it. The *Lessons* within a *Series* are related, and as such, the word should carry this meaning.)
- Theme (This means something else to programmers. A Theme is the look-and-feel of a website, like “I want my main colors to be Red and White, with a Nav-Bar on the Left”.)
- Subject (Better than theme, but still feels to specific.)
- Topic (Feels too specific, and doesn’t share the same vibe as *Course* and *Lesson*.
- Section (A “Course Section” is already a thing, if you’ve ever taken a college course. It’s basically the same Course with different Students.)
- Series (The current name, but has the issue of being a [defective noun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_plurals#Defective_nouns).)

To define what I’m looking for, in case it helps:

> A Collection of *Lessons* that share some common Theme, Goal, Subject, or Topic, but still a subset of a *Course*, which contains many of these.

If for some reason you think that I was wrong to reject one of the words I’ve already considered, then please let me know why you think that word is really the best choice.

Comment: A *program* maybe? Though that may be ambiguous in the context of a *programming* course :)

Comment: I guess I hadn't considered that, given my profession. Good thought, but it's still a bit iffy to me.

Comment: *Section* makes the most sense to me, but since you say that won't work, perhaps *segment*?

Comment: @Boom You could always disambiguate by using the British *programme*.

Comment: Hmm. I like *segment*. It doesn't ever refer to an existing term I already use, and it has a good meaning. I'll consider it, and see if someone else comes up with something better.

Comment: @Dan Bron The site will eventually be multi-language/multi-cultural. Also, in a world where a single misplaced character in a single line of code can blow up the entire program, spelling conventions like "colour" drive me crazy. I think I'll steer clear of *programme*. Nice idea though.

Comment: On Duolingo, the lessons are grouped into *skills*... may not work in all contexts, but it may be worth considering.

Comment: "Unit" would work. Try googling "Unit of Study."

Comment: @Jeff I'd +1 that as an answer.

Comment: The programmer in me immediately sees *Unit* as a Math term. Seeing as both Users and Developers will be using these terms, I don't want them to collide with other lingo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go with *Segment*, as @HollyK suggested (See the comments in the OP).

Thanks for everyone's help.

If you still have suggestions, I'd love to see them.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen the word "module" used for this.

Comment: As have I, but *module* means something else in my project.

Answer (score 1):

A *lesson set*.

Unless something more specific groups these particular lessons, this is about as good as it gets, AFAIK.

Comment: I'm looking for One-Word answers. Something like `LessionSet` just doesn't seem as clean to me.

Answer (score 1):

*Subcourse*.

I have experience being university lecturer (actually senior lecturer, so I did the whole set of activities about my courses). And I use term *subcourse* in my CV.

"An academic course making up part of a larger course." - https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subcourse

Comment: *Subcourse* is definitely the more direct term, but it doesn't seem elegant enough, as just using a *sub* prefix feels like cheating.

Comment: I agree that it does not elegant enough. But I did not find more relevant for my CV. Many words in many langs use prefixes and it is ok. Langs are alive and people define them in their speech - not by rules.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *[chapter](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=chapter)*

> One of the main divisions of a relatively lengthy piece of writing, such as a book, that is usually numbered or titled.

*American Heritage Dictionary*

Comment: Chapter seems too book-like to me, which makes it seem too specific on the wrong idea.

Answer (score 0):

**Curricula**?  Or would that be too broad, like a set of Courses?

Comment: To my understanding, it would indeed be too broad.

Comment: Yeah. Corricula to me seems like it should oversee Courses, not Lessons.

Comment: Hi @PeteK, welcome to ELU. As a quick note, I recommend giving definitions, backed up with online dictionary links, when proposing words as answers to questions.

Answer (score -1):

Sections or Units are commonly used in grade schools

Comment: This would benefit from more information.  The system flagged it as low quality, so I encourage you to [edit] after seeing the [help].